# Filter documents in MongoDB Compass on Epoch field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document:

```
{
  "_id": "5d646d78a6e3fe3834e448e4",
  "uniqSessionId": "2ce971c7-337b-0285-b569-a555659a1fc7",
  "userDeviceInformation": {
    "os": "Windows",
    "osVersion": "10",
    "browser": "Chrome",
    "browserVersion": "76.0.3809.100",
    "browserMajorVersion": 76,
    "screen": "3840 x 1200",
    "mobile": false
  },
  "mark": "show-main-image",
  "startDate": "1566862710321",
  "endDate": "1566862711787",
  "duration": 1466.4250000023
}
```

startDate and endDate are epoch timestamps.

How do I query? (I see part of my problem is mixing up date formats)

I have tried:

```
{"startDate":{$gt:Date(1503781020)}}
```

I am testing using MongoDB Compass Community.

I just upgraded from MongoDB 3.6 to 4.2

Gina

Comment: The value you are passing in ```Date()``` is in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: milliseconds, I would be happy to pass 2019/08/27xxxx as well

Comment: I tried {"startDate":{$gt:ISODate("2018-03-30T13:06:05.739-07:00")}} as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like you have to force it to convert to a long, so I multiplied by 1

{"startDate":{$gt:ISODate("2018-03-30T13:06:05.739-07:00")*1}}

Gina

Answer (score 0):

The `startDate` and `endDate` are strings. Thus we need to convert the value to be searched to string before comparison.

The following is an example:

```
db.collection.findOne({"startDate":{$gte: 1566862710322+""}})
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to work. I don't get back the records I am expecting (any records).

Comment: can you please post some sample document and the timestamp you are using to search?

Answer (score 0):

From python point of view, you can use below code

```
db.collection.findOne({"startDate":{"$gte": str(1566862710322)}})
```